# Regular Expression to place ? or ! if detected in the original word

Tags: java, regex

I have a Stemmer function that will return the stem word and place a period if it detected a period in the original word.

This is the code:

```
static String stemWord(Stemmer s, String word) throws Exception
{
    return s.StemWordWithWordNet(word)
    + (word.charAt(word.length()-1) == '.'?"?":"" );
}
```

So when I input a word into the stemWord function, it will place a dot at the end of the word if it detected 1 in the original word. Example

```
placing. -> place.  //notice it place a dot if it detects a dot in the original word
ate -> ate //no dot
```

Now how do I modify the regular expression so that it will place a ? or ! if it detected one.

```
going? -> go?
reading! -> read!
```

Comment: that's not what your code example appears to do...  can't you just write an if or case statement?

Comment: String.endsWith() function can be used to make the if condition more readable

Comment: Try `return s.StemWordWithWordNet(word) + word.replaceFirst("(?s)^.*?([!?.]?)$", "$1")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regex that contains a set of valid ending punctuation that you want to duplicate on your stemmed word:

```
private static final Pattern PUNCTUATION_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("[.?!]$");

static String stemWord(Stemmer s, String word) throws Exception {
    String word = "testing.";
    String stem = s.StemWordWithWordNet(word);

    Matcher m = PUNCTUATION_PATTERN.matcher(word);
    String endingPunctuation = m.find() ? m.group() : "";

    return stem + endingPunctuation;
}
```